# How do I print a Google Calendar in monthly view that shows multiple lines of an event?

Tags: google-calendar

Our church calendar is a Google Calendar, so I can import into other tools.  It appears that when Google Calendar is printed the description is cut off instead of wrapped within the day.

Is there a way to print a monthly calendar that will show full description using an import of Google Calendar?

[Many of our church members do not use smart phones or computers, so they want monthly paper copies of the calendars]